# Is there a virtual machine for javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a virtual machine for javascript?

Comment: Plenty. Pretty much every browser has one. Depends on your definition of virtual machine though, some might consider it simply an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search turns out that for Chrome it's V8, which you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/v8/). Maybe a similar project page exists for other browsers, but I'm not aware of them. You could also consider [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino%5F%28JavaScript%5Fengine%29) and similar solutions.